# Html Form / jQuery: Changing input with tab reduces numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

It's happening a weird thing on my form built with Html and jQuery. Basically I've created a stupid function that detracts a percentage (my platform fees) from the amount inserted into the first input and place the recalculated one into the second. Of course it happens reversely.

It's something like:

- Input 1: What you offer
- Input 2: What you receive (detracted of my platform fees)

[image]

As you can see through the image (more or less), when I insert into the first input **1000**, the second input will be filled with **930** if my percentage is 7%. Pretty straight.

The issue happens when I press tab from the first input to the second. The second stays with its value but the first **gets further detracted** of an undefined amount that I cannot identify or prevent. I don't know why, I'm probably missing something very stupid but I cannot see it.

Here is my **html**:

```
<div class="row top-15 form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>
            <?php _e('Your bid','dev'); ?>
        </h4>
        <p>
            <?php _e("Insert project's budget",'dev'); echo $budget;?>
        </p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3"><?php echo $currency ?></span>
            <input type="number" name="mybid" id="bid" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $bid; ?>" placeholder="<?php _e(" How much you offer ", "dev ") ?>" data-alert="<?php _e('Please type in a bid value.','dev'); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>
            <?php _e("You will receive",'dev'); ?>
        </h4>
        <p>
            <?php printf(__("%s of fees", 'dev'), '-' . $Dev_fee_after_paid . '%') ?>
            <span id="fees" data-fees="<?php echo $Dev_fee_after_paid ?>"></span>
        </p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3"><?php echo $currency ?></span>
            <input type="number" name="total" id="total" class="form-control" value="" size="10" placeholder="<?php _e(" What you get ", "Dev ") ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My jQuery**

```
var currency = $('#make-application').attr('data-currency');
var setFees = $('#fees').attr('data-fees');
var bid = $('#bid').val();
var fees = (bid/100)*setFees;
// $("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));
$("#fees").text(' = ' + fees.toFixed(0) + currency);
$('#bid, #total').on('focusout', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#bid").on('keyup', function(e){
    var newbid = $(this).val();
    var newfees = (newbid/100)*setFees;
    var total = newbid-newfees;
    if($(this).hasClass('error')){
        $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
    if($.isNumeric(newbid) === false){
        $(this).addClass('error');
        return;
    }
    if(newbid > 0){
        $("#total").val(total.toFixed(0));
        $("#fees").text(' = ' + newfees.toFixed(0) + currency);
    } else {
        $("#total").val('');
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 9) { //fixing the typed value in case of tab press
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       $(this).val(newbid);
    }
});
$("#total").on('keyup', function(e){
    var totalTwo = $("#total").val();
    var feesTwo = (totalTwo/100)*setFees;
    var bidTwo = (+feesTwo)+(+totalTwo);
    if($(this).hasClass('error')){
        $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
    if($.isNumeric(bidTwo) === false){
        $(this).addClass('error');
        return;
    }
    if(totalTwo > 0){
        $("#bid").val(bidTwo.toFixed(0));  
        $("#fees").text(' = ' + feesTwo.toFixed(0) + currency);
    } else {
        $("#bid").val('');
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 9) { //fixing the typed value in case of tab press
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       $(this).val(totalTwo);
    }
});
```

As you can see I've tried to `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` on `keycode == 9` without success. Could you give me some direction please?

Comment: Have you tried using a different event? I don't think on keyup is the proper event. that would fire every time a key is pressed (which would, in turn, deduct strange amounts). I think .focusout() is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ThomasK mmm what do you suggest? I mean, I'd need that the value is constantly updated while typing. `keydown`? I've tried focusout() in the past but it's not really something I like. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I just noticed that the if statement is at the end. Move it to the top and return. I think the value is updating before you check for the tab key.

Another solution would be to add a button. And calculate the value on the listener of that button.

Comment: @ThomasK you win. It works now. Let's write an answer!

Comment: just did. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is wrong.  If your math was right it wouldn't matter if you update one box from the other, and then immediately do the opposite.

```
rightbox = leftbox * (1 - setfees / 100)
```

so

```
leftbox = rightbox / (1 - setfees / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put input into the first box, you update the second box:

```
var newbid = $(this).val();
var newfees = (newbid/100)*setFees;
var total = newbid-newfees;

newbid:                 1000
newfees: (1000/100)*7 = 70
total:   1000-70      = 930
```

Then, when tab is pressed, the keyup event is fired on the second box, which in turn updates the first box:

```
var totalTwo = $("#total").val();
var feesTwo = (totalTwo/100)*setFees;
var bidTwo = (+feesTwo)+(+totalTwo);

totalTwo:              930
feesTwo: (930/100)*7 = 65
bidTwo:  65+930      = 995
```

You should change how the events fire, as well as your logic calculating the values.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if it is a tab press at the end of the function. Try putting it to the top.

```
var currency = $('#make-application').attr('data-currency');
var setFees = $('#fees').attr('data-fees');
var bid = $('#bid').val();
var fees = (bid/100)*setFees;
// $("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));
$("#fees").text(' = ' + fees.toFixed(0) + currency);
$('#bid, #total').on('focusout', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#bid").on('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 9) { //fixing the typed value in case of tab press
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       $(this).val(newbid);
    }
    var newbid = $(this).val();
    var newfees = (newbid/100)*setFees;
    var total = newbid-newfees;
    if($(this).hasClass('error')){
        $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
    if($.isNumeric(newbid) === false){
        $(this).addClass('error');
        return;
    }
    if(newbid > 0){
        $("#total").val(total.toFixed(0));
        $("#fees").text(' = ' + newfees.toFixed(0) + currency);
    } else {
        $("#total").val('');
    }
});
$("#total").on('keyup', function(e){
    var totalTwo = $("#total").val();
    var feesTwo = (totalTwo/100)*setFees;
    var bidTwo = (+feesTwo)+(+totalTwo);
    if(e.keyCode == 9) { //fixing the typed value in case of tab press
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       $(this).val(totalTwo);
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('error')){
        $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
    if($.isNumeric(bidTwo) === false){
        $(this).addClass('error');
        return;
    }
    if(totalTwo > 0){
        $("#bid").val(bidTwo.toFixed(0));  
        $("#fees").text(' = ' + feesTwo.toFixed(0) + currency);
    } else {
        $("#bid").val('');
    }

});
```